# Python Web Scraping td class span

Tags: python, html, web, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

New to Python and Web Scraping... I have been looking to scrape the highlighted section of code so I can retrieve the numbers 1.16, 7.50 and 14.67, but am having no joy in using a td, class, table-matches__odds pageSoup.find_all... anyone know what I'm missing here?

I'm using beautifulsoup 4.

[image]

Comment: Philip: People go spare on here if you (a) don't show code you've written in attempts to solve the problem yourself, and (b) give us pictures rather than text. Also, it helps if you can tell us what url you're attempting to process, if you can.

Comment: Sorry... when I try this, I just get blanks whenever I run it, tried changing the number in [] as well.  Other = pageSoup.find_all("td", {"class": "table-matches__odds"})

Other[0].text  The url I'm looking to parse is: http://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/scotland/premiership-2016-2017/results/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Awkward.

First I found the column of 'ratio' items (odds?), as reference points within the rows we want to plunder. Put them in the list called `ratio`.

Then I had a look at the next siblings for a typical element of `ratio`, namely the first.

You're interested only in the first row of the table, therefore I picked up `ratio[0]` and asked for its next siblings, which are all `td` elements.

I then extracted what you want from each of these, depending on its internal stucture. The only complicated one was the first. I used the `descendants` iterator to get its descendants, asked for the innermost one, and then got that one's attribute.

```
>>> import bs4
>>> import requests
>>> page = requests.get('http://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/scotland/premiership-2016-2017/results/').text
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
>>> ratio = soup.findAll('td', attrs={'class': 'h-text-center'})
>>> ratio[0].findNextSiblings()
[<td class="table-matches__odds colored"><span><span><span data-odd="1.16"></span></span></span></td>, <td class="table-matches__odds" data-odd="7.50"></td>, <td class="table-matches__odds" data-odd="14.67"></td>, <td class="h-text-right h-text-no-wrap">21.05.2017</td>]
>>> len(ratio)
15
>>> zeroth_ratio_sibs = ratio[0].findNextSiblings()
>>> first_item = list(zeroth_ratio_sibs[0].descendants)[2].attrs['data-odd']
>>> first_item
'1.16'
>>> second_item = zeroth_ratio_sibs[1].attrs['data-odd']
>>> second_item
'7.50'
>>> third_item = zeroth_ratio_sibs[2].attrs['data-odd']
>>> third_item 
'14.67'
```

Comment: Thanks Bill for looking at this.  This works a treat!